# Switch case menu doesn`t exit program when type case

Tags: c

I've coded a calculator with a menu. I'm trying to use `switch case`. My problem is that the menu doesn't exit immediately with case 0 when the  program is asking about values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        float a = 0;
        float b = 0;
        int menu = 0;
        mainMenu();
        scanf_s(" %d", &menu);
        printf("Give a A:\n");
        scanf_s(" %f", &a);
        printf("Give a B:\n");
        scanf_s(" %f", &b);
        switch (menu) {
        case 0: {
            printf("Choice: 0\n");
            puts("Goodbye");
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            printf("Choice: 1\n");
            printf(" %f", add(a, b));
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            printf("Choice: 2\n");
            printf(" %f", sub(a, b));
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            printf("Choice: 3\n");
            printf(" %f", mul(a, b));
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            printf("Choice: 4\n");
            printf(" %f", div(a, b));
            break;
        }
        default: {
            printf("No action selected\n");
            break;
        }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Rob Deleting a question (even if a good idea) is beyond an appropriate edit. Instead please comment to recommend it.

Comment: @Yunnosch [It's a bit of a gray area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386186/should-you-edit-or-vote-to-close-questions-with-multiple-questions) If I left it, I would vote to close and so may others. Instead, he gets notice from my comment on the edit and I leave it alone.

Comment: So your program accepts a menu choice and two other values and then checks to see what all three values are afterward and you want it to check the menu choice and exit if 0 was entered and if 0 was not entered only then do you want to collect A and B?  If so, why not just put an if statement between collecting the menu choice and collecting the other two values.

Comment: @Rob Admittedly an applicable link. I will have to digest it. It does seem to focus on already answered questions (this one was not until after our comments). I am not happy with it, but I will keep that link and the upvoted answer in mind for the future (i.e. will not-like it silently...). Thanks for linking and answering.

Comment: One stylistic comment is that you don't need braces inside a case unless you want to declare a local variable in that scope.  It's probably easier to read without the extra nesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf_s(" %d", &menu);
if (menu == 0)
{
    printf("Choice: 0\n");
    puts("Goodbye");
    return 0;
}
```

you need to check if the input for menu is given zero or no. If the input for menu is zero, just return from there. You don't need to go deep down for rest of the inputs.

as per comment of @bruceg, remove the `case 0` from the switch.

Comment: If you do this, then you should get rid of the `case 0:` code, as it would be unreachable.

Comment: Yes, all the printf's for the `case 0` can be removed from switch and can be added inside this if  condition.

Comment: Is it possible to use if "exit" as a case 0?

Comment: you won't be needing it. because you are already returning 0, which means your code won't execute down to the switch for menu 0.